# Avocado tree wilting indoors

Tags: diseases, indoors, avocado

My indoors avocado plants have been looking worse and worse over the past couple months, even though they are receiving plenty of sun (summer in Australia).

Their leaves have been drooping, becoming spotted and gray, and for one of the trees actually dropping.

Is it a watering issue? Sun? Or a disease?

[image]
[image]

**Edit:** close-up of the back of a leave:

[image]

Comment: That looks like disease or nutrient deficiency to me - but I'm not an expert.  (Its likely not an issue with under or overwatering).

Comment: This looks like spider mites to me but I need a close up picture of the underside of the leaf

Comment: @kevinskio I added one at the bottom of the question.

Comment: @davidgo Seems right! That pale yellow toning on image_1 infers Magnesium deficiency. Top yellowed leaves in image_2  denote Nitrogen defiecy and image_3 is a sign of potassium deficiency. What kind of soil  have you been using, OP? Does your municipal water contain chelating agents? Feed your plants with micronutrient solution or any hydroponic nutrient mix pack. Feed them over three weeks with highly diluted solution of 19:19:19 NPK fertilizers.